# How to properly get absolute coordinates for a control on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm using method `convertRect` to get correct absolute frame for a specific control but it's not working as expected.

```
var convertedRect = _view.ConvertRectToView(_view.Frame, null);
```

Variable `convertedRect` changes nothing from original rect. I use this rect to draw something on screen using absolute coordinates. If I use `convertedRect`, my draw is off for about the height of the toolbar... so it seems I need to find the way to get the correct `y` that takes into account the very top of the screen.

The code is c# since it's a Xamarin project, but the question also applies to swift or objective-c

**EDIT**

Something that may explain my confusion is the following test: I execute this on a ViewController expecting rect to change, but it doesn't

```
var rect = this.View.ConvertRectToView(this.View.Bounds, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks to me like your code should be

```
var convertedRect = _view.ConvertRectToView(_view.bounds, null);
```

A view's bounds is expressed in it's own coordinate system, but the frame is expressed in it's superview's coordinate system. Note that since you're passing in nil for the target view, your results should be in the window coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks. Using this I get the same rect as `_view.bounds`, nothing changes either. Do this mean my rect is already on window coordinates? The view belongs to the root view but clearly something is off since coordinates are not correct. When I use convertedRect to draw on screen, `y` is off by the size of the toolbar